# How to hide page name and extention from url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to hide all my page names and extension from url,

```
htt://www.domain.com/innerpage.php
to
http://www.domain.com/
```

and

```
http://www.domain.com/subfolder/innerpage.php
to
http://www.domain.com/subfolder/
```

and

```
http://www.domain.com/subfolder/subfolder/innerpage.php
to
http://www.domain.com/subfolder/subfolder/
```

I used like

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/subfolder/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/subfolder/subfolder/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```

its not work

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you

```
DirectoryIndex innerpage.php index.php index.html index.htm
```

Put this as first line of your `.htaccess`. This directive will look for `innerpage.php` if no page has been specified for a directory. If you want to hide **all** pages in your site URL's then it's not a good idea IMO.

Answer (score -1):

Give this set of directives a try:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?$ /innerpage.php
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /$1/innerpage.php
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /$1/$2/innerpage.php

RewriteRule ^innerpage.php$ / [R]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/innerpage.php$ /$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/innerpage.php$ /$1/$2 [R]
```

And be surprise what will happened...

Comment: I have the same problem, what happend was "server internal error 500".

Comment: @marc_s Did you give the set of directives above a try?